# Zoom in/out clicked area in Unity3D

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I am new to game development and also new to Unity. I need to zoom and move camera to clicked position of object. Actually I have imported an object with sub prefabs and all of prefabs has 0,0,0 position so not performing.

Please advice me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code you already have ? Also what do you mean by zoom and move ? (like look to the object and zoom or literally move the camera to the object ?)

Comment: Look up ScreenToWorldPoint and difference between localPosition and Position. From this you can figure out what to do. If not, you can post what you tried with these

Comment: I just want to show the selected part of human body in the center of view and also highlight clicked part of an object.

You can see example [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecM9nD2O3Oc) 

Please look at this and guide me @Kardux

Comment: @AyazRafai I think what _Umair M_ posted is what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

From what you described in question, here is what I can suggest:

You can calculate a point at certain distance where you think your camera should be from your body part object (for example x and y can be same as body part but z can have an offset of 5). And then use [MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html) on camera to move it to that certain point. After that you can apply [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)(bodypartObjectTransform).

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks **Umair** for your help.

Yes dude this working on all other objects i.e. Cube, Sphere. But here am getting selected body part transform.position is zero (0,0,0). So it will not working here...